# Google Docs Scripts addToFolder

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to use Google Docs' ability to run scripts to create the necessary folder structure for new clients (to upload content/images into). Here's what I have thusfar:

```
/**
 * This script creates the necessary folder structure for a new client
 */
function newClientSetup() {

  var initial = DocsList.getFolder("Clients");
  var client = DocsList.addtoFolder.createFolder("Client Name");
  var file = DocsList.addtoFolder(client);

};
```

Now this is not working (`TypeError: Cannot call method "createFolder" of undefined. (line 7)`), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the `Folder` class within `DocList`. I saw that `DocsList` has a `createFolder` method, that I could use like:

```
var folder = DocsList.createFolder("Folder Name");
```

but I'm trying to start off with a parent folder, called `Clients` (already in Google Docs) and then create the following structure:

```
Clients
    Client Name
        Content
        Images
```

Ideally I could run this script, but pass in a variable for `Client Name` to actually create the client name, but I haven't found much help from the docs. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how it works, see comments :

```
function createSubFolder(subfolder) { // the argument is the name of the folder you want to create
    var parentfolder = DocsList.getFolder('Clients'); //begin in the client folder (you could also open by Id, I prefer the ID as I find it more failsafe (ID are unique, names aren't necessarily 
    var newFolder = DocsList.createFolder(subfolder); // create the new subfolder from the argument of the function
    newFolder.addToFolder(parentfolder);// add the newly created folder to 'Clients'
}
```

to test this function simply use something like this :

```
function test(){
    createSubFolder('test');// this will create a new folder called test in your Clients folder
}
```

note : *to get the ID of your folder, take the value right behind folders/ in the url of the folder. Example in **bold*** : https://drive.google.com/?hl=fr&tab=wo#folders/**0B3qSFxxxxxxxxxdsMTFZMDQ**

The sequence might be much longer if you have more folder levels... but the structure is always the same and is unique for every folder.

Comment: I'm loving the simplicity of this one! Looks like I was kinda half-way there, but some core JS knowledge woulda helped a bit ;) I definitely agree that by ID is the better-way here. I was looking at @mhawksey solution below and was wondering if the check to see if a folder exists is "necessary" or not. I ran the same function twice (with the same subfolder name) and since Google handles folders by ID rather than name, the function didn't try to insert folders within the existing `test` folder I created (it was separate). Thanks!

Comment: Also (more of a general question), when running scripts, is there an easier way of passing in that `subfolder` argument (without having to go into the script to run it)? For example, a project manager will be creating the subfolder structure for each client -- I wasn't sure if Google has modal pop-ups that can pass along this information (more of a wish here for "best case scenario" but was wondering if you are familiar with that). Thanks!

Comment: You can enter folders name many many ways... The simplest would be to use `Browser.inputBox(prompt)` but you could also more elegantly build a UI to create data. Also, depending on how you get Client names it could be fully automated but I don't know so much about your use case.

Comment: Hi Serge - appreciate the continued input here - I'll definitely look into what you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function and some code I wrote which might help you. It uses a sub function to see if the folder already exists and if it doesn't makes it. If the folder does already exist it returns that object which helps with chaining ([referenced here on how it is used](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2012/06/using-google-apps-script-to-fast-track-student-feedback-behind-the-code/)):

```
function newClientSetup() {
   var ROOT_FOLDER = "Clients";
   var CLIENTNAME_FOLDER = "Client Names";

   // get a the system route folder (if it deosn't existing make it 
   var rootFolder = folderMakeReturn(ROOT_FOLDER); 
   // create/get draft and release folders 
   var clientNamesFolder = folderMakeReturn(CLIENTNAME_FOLDER,rootFolder, ROOT_FOLDER+"/"+CLIENTNAME_FOLDER);   
}

// function to see if folder exists in DocList and returns it 
// (optional - if it doesn't exist then makes it) 
function folderMakeReturn(folderName,optFolder,optFolderPath){ 
   try { 
      if (optFolderPath != undefined){ 
         var folder = DocsList.getFolder(optFolderPath); 
      } else { 
         var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName); 
      } 
      return folder; 
   } catch(e) { 
      if (optFolder == undefined) { 
         var folder = DocsList.createFolder(folderName); 
      } else { 
         var folder = optFolder.createFolder(folderName); 
      } 
      return folder; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question/answer is 3 years old and it was correct earlier, but this solution is no more working correctly with Google Apps script as on 2015, current easiest way to create a subfolder on a specific folder is,

```
function createSubFolder(parentId, folderName)
{
  var id="";
  try
  {
    var parent=DriveApp.getFolderById(parentId);   // get parent folder
    var folder =parent.createFolder(folderName);   // create sub folder 
    id=folder.getId();                             // get the subfolder id to return
  }
  catch(e)
  {
  }
  return id;
}
```

pass the parent folder id with the sub folder name you want to create, the Folder class has the method createFolder to create a folder under it which returns the created subfolder's object.